# How can I make a comma disappear in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my situation, I need to append ',' to separate each img in order to implode(), but I don't want to show the comma between each img, how can I css the visibility of the comma. By the way, I cannot use space +" ", why, because I have text and space between them, if I use space, then it will broke those word too.

```js
   imag=$('.result_tag:last').append('<img src="remove_sign.png">'+',');
```

Comment: what is `implode()`?

Comment: I'm finding very very hard to understand your simple question :)

Comment: try html encode the comma

Comment: @conan I'm not sure whats going on here. Why do you need to append `,` to separate each `<img>`? Should I understand you are doing `implode()` in PHP? And in that case, do you realize you can `implode()` without a separator?

Comment: Thanks for you time, I cannot do it in PHP. I need to explode it in PHP, so that's why I need to separate it with comma, why again? you know, when the code become very complicate, we have to complied with other code. Anyway, thanks for your time, I figure out a way to use space to separate it.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
.result .tag:last-child:after {
  content:",";
}
```

```js
   var imag = $('.result .tag:last')
   .append('<img width=50px height=50px style=background-color:sienna; />');
```

```css
.result .tag:last-child:after {
  content:",";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="result">
  <div class="tag">a</div>
  <div class="tag">b</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you will add multiple img tags in a loop. If it is true, I would like to create an array and push the each img tag string into the array and then using join() to a string and appending this string to the $('.result_tag:last') selector.

Try to something like this,

```
var arr =[];
var length=5;
for(var i <length; i++){
  arr.push('<img src="remove_sign.png">');
}
imag=$('.result_tag:last').append(arr.join());
```